# Duplicating content from another site and adding value (summaries, statistics) - ranking and courtesy

Tags: duplicate-content

I am working on a site that takes a governmental data base, provides a number of statistical and other summaries and also post the original data.

However this data (mostly long pieces of text) is also published on the official governmental site (without the added value of summaries).

Should I worry about google ranking due to this duplication? What is the preferred way to point to the official source of the information?

There is no advertisement on my site. My site is ".com". The governmental site is ".bg".

EDIT: There is additional markup for the text, generated after searching it for keywords, so just providing a link to it will not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the ratio of your content to the original one is important.

But, it's very important also what the people think, You may be "punished" for using much content from other site, but if your added content is really useful for your visitor, then you will be accessed more times, the people will link to you more and will talk about your site more.

Also, remember to put the link to the original source. Google may find that you are copying information, which by itself is not bad, but it will also find that you are giving credit (link) to that source. If you don't mention the source, it's easier to consider it just stealing.

Another thing you should consider, is complementing your sources, that transforms you site from a duplicate one to a comparative one, plus you offer much better service to the visitor and as I said, that improves the overall situation.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Depends on amount of original content you provide, especially if you provide statistical summaries, Google do not like statistics that much. Make a basic comparison between the length of the original text and your own content. If you have less content than the government text, this will probably be painful.

I would only use my own content, extract small parts of very relevant content from the original text (like quotes) when these parts are useful for the visitor. Link to the full text on the government site a the start or at the bottom of the page (put it where it is useful for the visitor).

Comment: I provide additional markup for the text, hence just providing a link will not suffice.